# Error while importing POM.xml as Mule project in Anypoint Studio 3.5

Tags: eclipse, import, mule, mule-studio

I am getting the following error when trying to import a maven project using pom.xml into Anypoint studio 3.5

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clean

Error
Fri Jun 27 18:41:21 EDT 2014
Error While Importing 

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner.runWithMuleProjectThrowingCoreException(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:89)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.ImportPackageManager.callMuleProjectRunner(ImportPackageManager.java:298)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.ImportPackageManager.doImportWithoutCopyToWorkspace(ImportPackageManager.java:273)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.ImportPackageManager.run(ImportPackageManager.java:85)
    at org.mule.tooling.ui.wizards.MuleProjectImportJob.runInWorkspace(MuleProjectImportJob.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.tooling.core.utils.CoreUtils.generateFlowsFromConfigs(CoreUtils.java:457)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.ImportPackageManager$2.call(ImportPackageManager.java:267)`enter code here`
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.ImportPackageManager$2.call(ImportPackageManager.java:1)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner.runWithMuleProjectThrowingCoreException(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:85)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: you might want to include more about what is being input.

Comment: i am trying to import a mule project from David Dossot's mule in action   site

Comment: Looks like a Studio bug. Report the issue to MuleSoft.

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar issue and by deleting .projects and .classpath file from  project directory it works.

.projects and .class path will contain information/dependency associated with any other IDE that is used before. Removing and importing the project will create it without any issue.

Comment: Please elaborate, e.g. explain why it does not work and why your suggestion should.

Comment: @Jonas come on man ... it just works ... black magic :D just let it be!